# Can Someone explain this compound interest formula to me.

Tags: calculus

$$A(t) = 1000 \left(1 + \frac{0.30}{365}\right)^{365 t}$$

$T$ is the number of days and 30 % is the amount charged daily. $1000$ is the initial loan amount. I understand that $0.30/ 365$ gets you the annual interest rate compounded per year but I do not understand the role of the exponent.

Also, what kind of function is this and is it continuous or discontinuous.

Comment: It is a continuous function which has no discontinuities or singularities. If $t$ is the number of days then why is it $365t$ in the exponent?

Comment: @AAYUSHJAISWAL:  I will assume that $365$ implies $365$ days. Therefore, I am sure you will agree that based on the above formula, 30% is the annual interest rate. $365$ is the number of compounding periods per year. Since this annual interest rate ($30%$) is compounded daily, the effective interest rate is $\frac{0.3}{365}$. Finally, confirm that in the exponent, $t$ represent the number of years, and not days. This means the number of compounding periods in $t$ years is $365\times t$. Finally, the function as written above is only defined for $t \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In addition to the corrections noted by @WinterSoldier ($t$ is the time in years, not days, and $30\%$ is the annual interest rate), note that the formula gives the amount $A(t)$ owed at time $t$, not the interest as suggested by your title.